# android: google maps API. Show route history

Tags: android, google-maps, path, gps, trace

I'm building a sport/running app, at the moment I can just see the usual blue dot related to my position, I'm trying to figure out how to show on the map the history of my path during the running session, so that I can see my path in realtime and check the full path ather the training.

For this goal is there a built in class/method in the googlemaps api or do I need to do something from scratch?

Please give me the main steps/topics that I need to study.

ie. I would like to have the same path history feature that's builtin in apps like "sports tracker", "endomondo", "Runtastic", etc...

Thanks.
Luther

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few logic about path history :

1. You will need [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polylines) to draw route history
2. Set `starting location`
3. Begin listening to location change and after x seconds, save this as your `final location`
4. Save the `starting location` and `final location` into a `List of coordinates`
5. use the `final location` as your new `starting location`, repeat step 3 until finish running
6. Draw polyline using coordinates from your `List of coordinates`

There, a basic logic for your question, please do more research and try making some code before asking further questions :)

Comment: this was the answer i was looking for, and this is good point to start researching. Thanks